# how to remove this error in pcl?

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "pcl_conversions"
with any of the following names:

```
pcl_conversionsConfig.cmake
pcl_conversions-config.cmake
```

after running catkin_make to build the pcl package this error always comes, im tired of this error. o man.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235891/how-to-remove-this-error-in-pcl?/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2016-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should post here the package file and the cmake file, it seems like you didn't write them correctly. Anyway make sure you have these in the package.xml:

```
  <build_depend>pcl_conversions</build_depend>
  <build_depend>pcl_ros</build_depend>
 
  <run_depend>pcl_conversions</run_depend>
  <run_depend>pcl_ros</run_depend>
```

and then in the CMakeLists.txt file you should have something like this:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  pcl_conversions
  pcl_ros
)
target_link_libraries(executable_name
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  ${roslib_LIBRARIES}
  ${PCL_LIBRARIES}
)
```

I hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [marcozorzi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26988/marcozorzi/) with karma: 46 on 2016-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2016-06-02**:
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "pcl_ros" with any
of the following names:

```
pcl_rosConfig.cmake
pcl_ros-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "pcl_ros" to CMAKE_PRE

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2016-06-02**:
now this error is coming.

**Comment by [marcozorzi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26988/marcozorzi/) on 2016-06-02**:
Then try to add this one to the cmake file

```
## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
find_package(PCL 1.7 REQUIRED COMPONENTS)
```

Then give it a catkin_make clean and then again catkin_make an let me know.
Of course I am assuming that you have pcl 1.7 installed correctly

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2016-06-03**:
pcl 1.7 is installed, but still getting problems.

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2016-06-03**:
hurray it is finally working. i dont know exactly what was the problem, but after reinstalling the package and rewriting the codes, it is now not showing any error. thanks for your feedback sir, by the way.

**Comment by [marcozorzi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26988/marcozorzi/) on 2016-06-05**:
Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the problem by installing the pcl_conversions and pcl_ros packages.

```
$sudo apt-get update
$sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-pcl-conversions
$sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-pcl-ros
```

---

Originally posted by [Siteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/26714/siteen/) with karma: 53 on 2017-04-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3